# Separate mongoengine models in django 1.7

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I am using django 1.7 and mongoengine. I would like to separate my models in several files. With django models there is not problem. But with mongoengine Documents and can't figure out how to accomplish this task and still have access to django admin. One of the problems is that mongoengine _meta does not support app_label. The only way to keep working those models with django admin is keep mongoengine Documents in models/**init**.py. Because I have several models I would like another approach.

```
    Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:4080/admin/

    Django Version: 1.7
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Installed Applications:
     ('django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'account',
     'mongoadmin',
     'grappelli',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'rest_framework',
     'notifications',
     'django_extensions',
     'debug_toolbar_mongo',
     'autos',)
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
     'account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
      225.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
      204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
      399.                             'name': apps.get_app_config(app_label).verbose_name,
    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/garage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py" in get_app_config
      150.             raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)

    Exception Type: LookupError at /admin/
    Exception Value: No installed app with label 'models'.
```

I try to add app_label to meta but it didn't work. Also I try to override the metaclass and inject app_label just for this models but this also did't work as I expected. I could inject app_label in the dictionary that I think that have the values of meta. But I couldn't retrieve the value as I was expecting.

```
 
class CustomAutoMeta(TopLevelDocumentMetaclass):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        meta = MetaDict()
        super_new = super(CustomAutobahnMeta, cls).__new__
        # this approach does not work
        meta.merge({'app_label':'auto'})
        meta.merge(attrs.get('_meta', {}))
        attrs['_meta'] = meta
        attrs['_meta']['app_labels'] = 'auto'
        new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return new_class

class DocumentBase(Document):
    my_metaclass = CustomAutoMeta
    __metaclass__ = CustomAutoMeta

    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
    updated = DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            self.updated = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        super(DocumentBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    meta = {
        'abstract' : True,
    }

class Auto(DocumentBase):
    pass

# I can retrieve the value in this way
Auto._meta['app_label']

# But I can't retrieve it in this way
Auto._meta.app_label
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The error says you don't have an installed app called `models` and I can't see it in the Installed Applications list. Is that a red herring?

Comment: Does importing the individual Document classes into `models/init.py` fix it?

Comment: It says that models is not installed because my files which have the Documents models resides in models package.

Comment: When those classes are imported in models/__init__.py is when the error comes out. When the models are created inside of models/__init__.py is when everything is ok. What I think that django does with django.db.models is base on the path split it and add app_label property to the model, very top in the metaclass.